# brew install veclibfort: gfortran: No such file or directory

Tags: homebrew, gfortran

As a prereq to octave, I need to install veclibfort:

```
brew install veclibfort
```

I get the error

```
==> make check
gfortran -o tester -O tester.f90 vecLibFort.o -framework vecLib
make: gfortran: No such file or directory
make: *** [check] Error 1
```

That error sounds like I don't have gfortran installed, but I do. If I run `gfortran -v`:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gfortran
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.8.3/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.2.0/4.8.3/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.2.0
Configured with: ../configure --build=x86_64-apple-darwin13.2.0 --(snip)
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.3 (GCC)
```

This issue seems to be addressed here:

https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science/issues/992

but there doesn't seem to be a relevant solution.

Comment: Is gfortran installed via the old gfortran formula or the new gcc formula?

Comment: I have no idea. How do I check? I presume new is better than old?

Comment: `brew uninstall gfortran` should tell you if it's installed. If it runs, then that formula was installed. Then also uninstall `gcc` and reinstall only `gcc`. Should be no harm.

Comment: `brew uninstall gfortran` didn't find the "keg". Uninstalling and reinstalling gcc completely fixed the issue. veclibfort installed perfectly after that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I simply had to reinstall gcc:

```
brew uninstall gcc
brew install gcc
```

After that veclibfort installed perfectly. thanks to kmm for the answer. He posted as a comment, I'm posting as an answer that I can mark as accepted.